# Why is linux so popular?

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux and i want to know 
 Why is the GNU/Linux a popular operating system? 
 Why are there so many forks of it? 
 Why is it used by most of the world's pro and some ordinary users? 
 Why is it used so widely on the systems of most of the world's companies? 
 Why does it power the world's largest supercomputers? 
 Why are there so many fans of it? 
And most important Question of all : 
 **Why is it more preferred than other operating systems available?**

Answer (score 1):

Although the question assumes opinions poll which contradicts with `stackexchange` question policies, I will try to give some reasons, which are biased of course.

- it's free (Of course you may buy an enterprise-level support services from different companies if you wish);
- it's opensource
- it's much less prone to virus infections (there are much less vectors to attack so you need not to run A/V software that monitors programs activity at runtime) compare to some other OSes and associated software.
- it's very well manageable, scaleable and extensible.

And finally, an answer for the last question you have highlighted with bold.

It is not preferred. Every thing serves someone's needs with some quality for some costs. The balance of quality and costs matters.